# Install 13.04 as base OS without ANY windows. Install on RAW disk

Tags: boot, wubi, live-cd

To whom it may concern,

I am having an issue finding a live install iso for Ubuntu that I can boot my daughters laptop with to install Ubuntu again.  Her last installation of Ubuntu 12.04 (upgraded from 11.?) crapped out and locked up.  I'm in the process of recovering her /home information to my NAS for her to reload her files onto the new hard drive I installed.  I can't seem to find an installer without that god awful wubi.exe crap.  Can someone please point me to the installer that does not first insist I'm running Winblows first?

I have one, and only one Windows machine that my daughter uses to play SIMS (off the network).  Other than that every one of my machines is either Linux (Fedora/Ubuntu) or a Mac (my other daughter).  I wouldn't have the Windows machine if she had a Mac too, because SIMS runs on Apple Mac's.  Why do these developers not make it more apparent on the download page that this installer is for the starter people who want to test the waters within Windows.  I'm not a STARTER Linux user!  I want a base OS bootable iso that I can install the latest Ubuntu from.  If not, then my daughters laptop's will become Fedora Laptops.

Thank you,
Bill

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do with the Ubuntu Desktop version (the *.iso file) that you download from the Ubuntu site [**here**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). You can:

- Run the Wubi installer, to install within Windows
- Boot a Live CD/USB version where you can boot Ubuntu directly from the CD/USB
- Install Ubuntu onto the hard disk

When you make a bootable CD/USB with this *.iso file, and:

- If you insert the CD/USB while you are inside Windows, you'll be presented with the Wubi installer
- If you boot from that CD/USB as you are starting your machine, you'll be presented with an option to either "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" to the hard disk.

What you're looking for is that last point. So, create a bootable USB/CD from that *.iso file that you downloaded, and insert it into that computer with the RAW disk, and you'll be able to install Ubuntu onto it.

Comment: +1 Alaa.  I think the OP is assuming that just because there are Windows executables that he needs to have Windows installed.  @user158642 - Did you try to simply boot off of the .ISO disc at all yet?  You should have gotten Alaa's final point right away, if you did (as did I).

Comment: I tried booting off of the DVD that I burned from that 13.04 .ISO image.  It wouldn't boot, it just sat with a black screen and did nothing.  I heard the DVD initially spin up, but then it spun down very shortly after.  I rebooted and then selected the Optical device from the boot list, by manually overriding the BIOS defaults as well (F9 Select boot device).  The BIOS defaults are also setup to boot from this order, 1)Optical 2)USB 3)Internal disk.  I'll try again and see if I can boot one of my other desktops and see if there's perhaps corruption on the ISO image.

Comment: I mounted a new download of that same 13.04 ISO as a loop device on my Fedora workstation here at work and all of the files look exactly the same as the file list on the DVD I attempted to boot from.  I've also downloaded the 12.04 desktop version and I'll install that if this 13.04 doesn't work this time.  I know that works, I've used it before on another laptop.  I can then upgrade from that.  I have to say I REALLY like the upgrade feature within Ubuntu.  If I find a more friendly workstation layout that I like, then I just might defect from Fedora.

Comment: Yeah there might be something wrong with the ISO file. Also, I tend to not use CDs/DVDs anymore, I create a bootable USB instead (because, well, CDs aren't around anymore). I use the program called **LinuxLive USB Creator** (LiLi for short), that can be downloaded [**here**](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download), to create the bootable USB. I think it's a pretty awesome tool. It's simple. It's easy.

Comment: Even more fun:

ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso selected
Verifying filesystem...
Setting /dev/sdd1 label to LIVE
Verifying ISO MD5 checksum
There was a problem executing the following command: `checkisomd5 "/home/bille/Downloads/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso"`
A more detailed error log has been written to '/tmp/liveusb-creator.log'
ISO MD5 checksum verification failed

Comment: Found the MD5 checksum, but I already have 12.04LTS version installed and running.  I'm in the process of upgrading it to 13.04 now.  Thanks for the help.  The 13.04 version never did work for me.  I don't think it liked being burned to a DVD.  That's the only thing I can come up with.

Comment: So much for upgrading from 12.04LTS.  I tried it twice and it failed to upgrade to 12.10 TWICE.  It was locked up during boot with something in X failing.  I attempted to troubleshoot by manually updating via aptitude at the command line, but couldn't find anything in there that jumped out on why X-Windows was failing and locking me out of even an alternate command line window.  So my daughters laptop is stuck at 12.10LTS for the time being.  So much for my earlier praise of Ubuntu's upgrade capability.